# AngularJS - ngRepeat and ngMessages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-messages

I struggle to make ngMessages work in a ngRepeat loop. Please consider the following example :

```html
<form name="$ctrl.demoForm.$fc" novalidate>
  <div ng-repeat="tag in $ctrl.demoForm.tags track by $index">
    <div>
      <label>Tag:</label>
      <input name="tag{{$index}}" ng-model="tag.value" type="text" ng-pattern="/^[a-z]*$/">
      <button ng-click="$ctrl.removeTag($index)">Remove</button>
    </div>
    <ng-messages for="$ctrl.demoForm.$fc['tag'+$index].$error">
        <ng-message when="pattern">Must only contain letters.</ng-message>
    </ng-messages>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="$ctrl.addTag()">Add new tag</button>
</form>
```

I simply iterate over an array of tags stored in `$ctrl.demoForm.tags`. I'm aware that ng-repeat creates a new scope each iteration so each tag is an object like `{value: 'tag value'}`.

Here is the controller associated, very basic stuff:

```js
app.controller('DemoCtrl', function() {
  this.demoForm = {
    tags: [
      {value: 'tag 1'}, 
      {value: 'tag 2'}
    ]
  };

  this.addTag = function(){
    this.demoForm.tags.push({value: ''});
  };

  this.removeTag = function(index) {
    if (this.demoForm.tags.length > index) {
      this.demoForm.tags.splice(index, 1);
    }
  };
});
```

It works fine, I can add and remove tags normally. But, problems arise when a field has an error. If you try to remove a field **above** the field on error, their values get messed up.

The odd thing is that the good field is actually removed, only their values seems desynchronized when on error. I added an `id` attribute in the jsbin to illustrate the problem, you can find it here :

http://jsbin.com/nifipatojo/edit?html,js,output

Does anyone have an idea of what happen ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The bug does not happen...can't recreate what you are describing

Comment: I've added a description on the jsbin. Remove all tags then recreate 3 tags, set their value to 1, 2 and 3 and try to remove the first one. You can also only create 2 tags, set the value of the second one to "2" for example and try to remove the first tag.